# UrlRewriteFilter - combining redirect and forward rules

Tags: jsp, servlets, url-rewriting, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to tame urlrewritefilter, and it looks like 
like when one rule with redirect matchs another rule with forward I won't see the URL I'm redirecting in the address bar, as expected.

Here is a snippet of config:

```
<rule>
  <from>/patha</from>
  <to type="redirect">/pathb</to>
</rule>

<rule>
  <from>/pathb</from>
  <to type="forward">/pathc</to>
</rule>
```

What I am expecting to be done by this rules while I'm trying to access to `patha`

- Rule for `patha` redirect my browser to `pathb`, the URL in address bar *is changing*.
- Since this rule is not the last one, the rule for `pathb` is also a good match, so browser get forwarded to pathc, but, because this is forward, the URL in address bar *remains pathb*.

But actually what is happening is that I'm forwarding to pathc without any changes in address bar.

My question is: Why is this so and how I can actually achieve what I am seeking for?

**UPD:**
   I've tested urlrewritefilter forward with redirection in jsp via:

```
response.setStatus(302);
response.setHeader("Location", "pathb");
response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

The result is the same - URL is not rewritten.

Answer (score 6):

What you are noticing is the expected behaviour. With `forward` you will never see the URL in the browser. Please see below differences between `forward` and `redirect`:

**Forward**

- a forward is performed internally by the servlet, the browser is completely unaware that it has taken place, so its original URL
- remains intact any browser reload of the resulting page will simple repeat the original request, with the original URL

**Redirect**

- a redirect is a two step process, where the web application instructs
  the browser to fetch a second URL, which differs from the original a
  browser reload of the second URL will not repeat the original
  request, but will rather fetch the second URL
- redirect is marginally slower than a forward, since it requires two
  browser requests, not one objects placed in the original request
  scope are not available to the second request